# Varchar to Timestamp but varchar data is yyyy-mm-dd-hh:mi:ss:ff format

Tags: oracle

My source is from Oracle and the col1 is varchar2(26) but the value looks like YYYY-MM-DD-hh:mi:ss:ff (Sample rec: 2014-08-15-02.03.34.979946).
I have to extract only 6 months records based on COL1. Since there is a hypen between date part and time part - i could not consider as timestamp. Is there any idea how to have this as timestamp to lookup only 6 months data.

Answer (score 2):

If it is possible at all, fix the data first. Storing timestamps in string data type is terrible. How do you know you don't have a time like 25:30:00 in the strings? Or a date like February 30? Besides, you can't really use an index on that column (so queries will be very slow), you will have to write a lot of code whenever referencing that column, etc.

Anyway - to deal with the immediate problem, use `TO_TIMESTAMP()`, exactly with the format model you show in your post - **including** the dash between the date part and the time part. Something like this:

```
select case when to_timestamp('2014-08-15-02.03.34.979946', 'YYYY-MM-DD-HH24:MI:SS.FF')
                 >= systimestamp - interval '6' month
            then 'TRUE' else 'FALSE' end
       as result
from   dual;

RESULT
------
FALSE
```

EDIT:  As Alex Poole points out (correctly as always) in a Comment below this Answer, `interval` arithmetic won't work correctly in all cases. It is better, than, to use something like

```
cast ( timestamp (...., format-model) as date ) <= add_months (sysdate, -6).
```

Comment: Interval arithmetic is a tricky unless you're working from the first of the month though, or at least not right at the end; subtracting that interval will error on 2017-08-29, or 2017-10-31, etc. I realise that's just an example, and the conversion part is right of course (it doesn't even need to be a dash in the middle, space would also work, thanks to the 'flexibility'), but maybe worth pointing out *8-)

Comment: @AlexPoole - Huh? I just checked, and indeed you are correct. Oracle is crazy. So `add_months(date '2017-01-31', 1)` works fine and produces the result `28-FEB-2017`, but `timestamp '2017-01-31 00:00:00' + interval '1' month` errors out? **WHY?????** (Of course, you can't answer that, unless you work for Oracle.)

Comment: I think @a_horse_with_no_name *may* have said once that it's part of the SQL standard, but not sure. (All my standard vs. Oracle info comes via our equine friend *8-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this will do:

```
select *
from your_table
where to_date(substr(col1,1,19),'yyyy-mm-dd-HH24.MI.SS') between add_months(sysdate,-6) and sysdate;
```

Assuming all the data format in col1 is always the same.

Also note that I used HH24 for hour segment, however could be not your case.

Answer (score 0):

You can include the dash in your format model, as @mathguy showed, to convert your string to a timestamp:

```
select to_timestamp('2014-08-15-02.03.34.979946', 'YYYY-MM-DD-HH24:MI:SS.FF') from dual;

TO_TIMESTAMP('2014-08-15-02.
----------------------------
15-AUG-14 02.03.34.979946000
```

although unless you explicitly tell it not to be via the `FX` modifier, Oracle is flexible enough to allow a dash even if the model has a space (see the text below [this table in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF51079):

```
select to_timestamp('2014-08-15-02.03.34.979946', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF') from dual;

TO_TIMESTAMP('2014-08-15-02.
----------------------------
15-AUG-14 02.03.34.979946000
```

However, converting all of the values in your `col1` column and then comparing them may be a lot of work, and will prevent any index on that string column being used. Given the format, you can convert your date range to string instead, and use string comparison; e.g. to find everything in the six months up to midnight this morning:

```
select col1 -- or whichever columns you need
from your_table
where col1 >= to_char(cast(add_months(trunc(sysdate), -6) as timestamp), 'YYYY-MM-DD-HH24:MI:SS.FF6')
and col1 < to_char(cast(trunc(sysdate) as timestamp), 'YYYY-MM-DD-HH24:MI:SS.FF6');
```

or since the time part can be fixed for that example, you can use character literals instead of casting:

```
select col1 -- or whichever columns you need
from your_table
where col1 >= to_char(add_months(sysdate, -6), 'YYYY-MM-DD"-00:00:00.000000"')
and col1 < to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD"-00:00:00.000000"');
```

Of course, storing data in the correct native data type would be a much better solution. Any other solution only works at all if your string data actually contains what you think, and the data is all sane (or as sane as it can be in the wrong data type).

Comment: I tried this. select (TO_TIMESTAMP('Col1', 'YYYY-MM-DD-HH24:MI:SS.FF')) from dual; But i am getting the error like "ora-01841 full year must be between 4713 and 9999 and not be 0"

Comment: @Jade - it should be `TO_TIMESTAMP(Col1, ,,,)`, not `TO_TIMESTAMP('Col1', ...)`. You are trying to convert the text literal `'Col1'`, not the contents of the `col1` column. Remove the single quotes around the column name. but then you have to select from your actual table, not `dual`.

Comment: Thanks Mr Alex. It works. Next i will look into your snippet to filter 6 months data. Thank you all

Comment: Using an index on a "timestamp" column stored in VARCHAR2 data type may work, but most often it will not. The issue is that estimates of rows will be way off. '2017-12-31' and '2018-01-01' are adjacent as dates, but not as strings; where an index may be used if the column was in the correct data type (and therefore the estimate would be for a small number of rows), if the column is VARCHAR2 the estimate may be large and the optimizer will choose a FTS. Tom Kyte had a great conference presentation exactly on this, with excellent examples along these lines.

Comment: Indeed, and fully agree about using the proper data type. This prevents every value in the table being converted though; if an index can be used that's a binus I suppose.